# Alternative to std::getline needed for reading a file

Tags: c++, file-io, c++11, getline

Consider the following method which reads a line from a text file and tokenizes it:

```
std::pair<int, int> METISParser::getHeader() {

    // handle header line
    int n;  // number of nodes
    int m;  // number of edges

    std::string line = "";
    assert (this->graphFile);
    if (std::getline(this->graphFile, line)) {
        std::vector<node> tokens = parseLine(line);
        n = tokens[0];
        m = tokens[1];
        return std::make_pair(n, m);
    } else {
        ERROR("getline not successful");
    }

}
```

A crash happens in `std::getline` (`pointer being freed was not allocated` - won't go into the details here). *The crash does not happen if I compile my code on other systems and is very likely not an error in my own code.* For the moment I am unable to fix this, and I don't have the time, so I'll just try to bypass it with your help:

Can you suggest an alternative implementation that does not use `std::getline`?

EDIT: I am on Mac OS X 10.8 with gcc-4.7.2. I tried in on SuSE Linux 12.2 with gcc-4.7, where the crash does not happen.

EDIT: One guess was that `parseLine` corrupts the string. Here is the code for completeness:

```
static std::vector<node> parseLine(std::string line) {

    std::stringstream stream(line);
    std::string token;
    char delim = ' ';
    std::vector<node> adjacencies;

    // split string and push adjacent nodes
    while (std::getline(stream, token, delim)) {
        node v = atoi(token.c_str());
        adjacencies.push_back(v);
    }

    return adjacencies;
}
```

Comment: Is the free in `std::string` code? What's the stack trace?

Comment: "other systems"? - what is your target system at the moment? on what platform doesn't this work?

Comment: @sth Yes. See the stacktrace here: https://gist.github.com/4603853

Comment: "and is very likely not an error in my own code" - I could argue about this, but as you don't have time for this, I won't.

Comment: If the cause of the free is the string, than likely the string (`line`) is the problem, not `std::getline`. Replacing `std::getline` probably won't help. My best guess is that `parseLine()` corrupts the string.

Comment: @KirilKirov At least it's an error that depends on the system on which I build as well as the context in which the code appears. I do not feel able to debug this or even correctly describe the error context.

Comment: @sth And what could be the reason that `parseLine` corrupts the string on OS X and not on Linux?

Comment: @cls - most probably, you have UB somewhere.

Comment: @sth: `parseLine` is called after `getline` and `line` is local that is not reused. Still I'm sure this is not a `getline` bug, but OP has corrupted the heap somewhere else.

Comment: @cls The reason might be an undefined behaviour invoked somewhere in your code that you did not show

Comment: What can I do to give more information or debug this undefined behavior?

Comment: I think Valgrind might be your next port of call for this (or a mac equivilent)

Comment: @cls: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @ybungalobill I think this might be suitable as a SSCCE: https://algohub.iti.kit.edu/parco/METISReaderTest/files/tip/

Comment: @Caribou This is the valgrind output: https://gist.github.com/4603986

Comment: @cls: There are places for potential UB: `getHeader` does not always return a value. `getHeader` may access beyond the `vector`'s bounds.

Comment: I've found the culprit for the crash: the `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` flag was set on my mac which was not set on the linux machine. If this is set, the crash happens. I've checked all compiler flags for equality and tried to remove them one by one. Thanks everybody for making me look into the original issue again.

Comment: A crash dump in a debug build that doesn't manifest in a release build is almost *always* a debug-check that is there for *your* protection trying to warn you something is wrong. Ignoring this is by linking only against release-libs is like "solving" the problem of broken brakes on your car by only driving toward things you can bounce off with hopefully minimal damage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always write your own slower and simpler `getline`, just to make it work:

```
istream &diy_getline(istream &is, std::string &s, char delim = '\n')
{
    s.clear();
    int ch;
    while((ch = is.get()) != EOF && ch != delim)
        s.push_back(ch);
    return is;
]
```